# How to use Markdownit modul with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, storyblok, markdown-it

I am using Nuxt, Vuetify and Storyblok. I have problem when I want to display markdown from storyblok. I try to use [Markdownit](https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/markdownit) modul.

First I install it with npm, then import to modules and use it with v-html, but still don't get expected results.
What I am doing wrong?

```
npm install markdown-it --save
```

```
modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/markdownit', {
      html: true,
      linkify: true,
      breaks: true,

    }],
    ['storyblok-nuxt', {
      accessToken: process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" ? "ygL5rmck1lGa42Vaai7x1Qtt" : 'iyPj3vEKmPladyz3zeqKuwtt',
      cacheProvider: 'memory'
    }]
  ],
```

```
<p v-html="content"></p>
```

Result

```
**Bold text**
![Img](//a.storyblok.com/f/56157/700x699/2a66b0316d/photo.jpg)
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your Vue controller too ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use the module, too. You're just importing it at the moment.

What I mean is to write

```
<p v-html="$md.render(content)"></p>
```

instead of

```
<p v-html="content"></p>
```